# Are proper classes useful in undergraduate mathematics?

Tags: set-theory

I know of a bunch of instances where there are collections we would like to talk about that form proper classes, like the class of all sets, the class of all singletons, the class of all relations, the class of all groups, etc. But when talking to my friend about them, he didn't see the usefulness of learning about proper classes, as he said he hadn't run into situations where they were necessary in the undergraduate math he's encountered (he wasn't claiming that there's no use for them, but that as far as he saw, there wasn't use for them in the math he's done). Is there undergraduate math where proper classes naturally arise and have use? This precludes areas like model theory and category theory.

Comment: Well, they tend to appear most often in foundational math, i.e., set theory, logic (model theory), category theory, but classes appear in almost every branch of mathematics. It is almost assumed that these classes behave "well" in these cases. If you are okay with this assumption, and not knowing what precisely I mean by "well", you don't need to explicitly learn about classes. If you do care, learning about classes more formally helps.

Comment: People use proper classes all the time. Every time someone says “for all groups $G$”, they’re quantifying over a proper class. There’s nothing complex or mysterious about them.

Comment: You can get pretty far in many mathematical disciplines with just naive set theory, as long as you don't worry too much about the foundations of the math you're doing. I think many mathematicians use naive set theory in practice when they work, knowing that if they wanted, they could bust out ZFC and do everything properly.

Comment: @Arthur: Unfortunately, most of them couldn't bust out ZFC even if you threat them with spoilers to all Marvel movies. But indeed, they *know* that *someone* could. And if they are smart, they also hired a lawyer in their department. I mean, they hired a set theorist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair enough. They know it can be done, even if they themselves can't necessarily do it.

Answer (score 5):

Is it useful to learn, as a young child, that you shouldn't cross a highway by foot, even if you grow up in a city and will not end up having to cross any highway by yourself anyway?

Yes. It is useful. Highways are dangerous, and learning about them as part of the dangers of crossing the road is important.

Proper classes are useful since they teach you that not everything is "as it may seem", and that you should at least be careful when talking about arbitrary collections.

For example, strictly speaking, there is a proper class of algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$. We know, however, that all of them are necessarily countable, and so we can therefore assume that they are all just subsets of some large enough set (e.g. the complex numbers). But formally speaking, this requires an argument. Even if you can ignore it, for "all practical reasons". To have a teacher not at least acknowledge this at some point during your undergraduate means that your university has no set theory lectures which will teach students these basics ideas; and other teachers don't feel compelled to point these things out (since hearing about proper classes for the first time in Galois theory is probably more confusing than helpful).

Now, having said that, it is quite true that people don't think about proper classes often. Many mathematicians will go through their entire career without having seen proper classes being mentioned or used in their research or related work. And that's fine. Some people live in rural villages and don't ever see a highway. But it's not that classes are not, or shouldn't, make appearances in ordinary mathematical educations on an undergraduate level. They definitely should, as should basics of set theory, of course.